# Generate Lucene segments_N file

Tags: java, solr, lucene

While moving Lucene index files from a server to an other, I forgot to move the segments_N file (because I use the pattern `*.*`)

Unfortunately I've erased the original folder, and I only have these files in my directory now :

```
_1rpt.fdt
_1rpt.fdx
_1rpt.fnm
_1rpt.nvd
_1rpt.nvm
_1rpt.si
_1rpt_Lucene50_0.doc
_1rpt_Lucene50_0.dvd
_1rpt_Lucene50_0.dvm
_1rpt_Lucene50_0.pos
_1rpt_Lucene50_0.tim
_1rpt_Lucene50_0.tip
write.lock
```

I am missing the `segments_42u` file, and without it I cannot even do an `org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex` :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found in MMapDirectory@/solr-5.3.1/nodes/node1/core/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@119d7047: files: [write.lock, _1rpt.fdt, _1rpt.fdx, _1rpt.fnm, _1rpt.nvd, _1rpt.nvm, _1rpt.si, _1rpt_Lucene50_0.doc, _1rpt_Lucene50_0.dvd, _1rpt_Lucene50_0.dvm, _1rpt_Lucene50_0.pos, _1rpt_Lucene50_0.tim, _1rpt_Lucene50_0.tip]
at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.checkIndex(CheckIndex.java:483)
at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.doMain(CheckIndex.java:2354)
at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.main(CheckIndex.java:2237)
```

The index is pretty huge (> 800GB) and it will take weeks to rebuild it.

Is there a way to generate this missing segment info file ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: i suggest asking this in Lucene user forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ameertawfik has suggested, I ask the question to Lucene mailing list, and they help me solving this issue.

Here is my solution, in case it could help someone else (add `lucene-core-x.x.x.jar` to the classpath) :

```
package org.apache.lucene.index;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.IOContext;
import org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory;

public class GenSegmentInfo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Codec codec = Codec.getDefault();
        Path myPath = Paths.get("/tmp/index");
        Directory directory = new SimpleFSDirectory(myPath);

        //launch this the first time with random segmentID value
        //then with java debug, get the right segment ID
        //by putting a breakpoint on CodecUtil#checkIndexHeaderID(...)
        byte[] segmentID = {88, 55, 58, 78, -21, -55, 102, 99, 123, 34, 85, -38, -70, -120, 102, -67};

        SegmentInfo info = codec.segmentInfoFormat().read(directory, "_1rpt",
                segmentID, IOContext.READ);
        info.setCodec(codec);
        SegmentInfos infos = new SegmentInfos();
        SegmentCommitInfo commit = new SegmentCommitInfo(info, 1, -1, -1, -1);
        infos.add(commit);
        infos.commit(directory);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Added the automation to find segmentID in Lucene62 without debugging:

```
package org.apache.lucene.index;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec;
import org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene62.Lucene62SegmentInfoFormat;
import org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedChecksumIndexInput;
import org.apache.lucene.store.ChecksumIndexInput;
import org.apache.lucene.store.DataInput;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.IOContext;
import org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.StringHelper;

public class GenSegmentInfo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            help();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Codec codec = Codec.getDefault();
        Directory directory = new SimpleFSDirectory(Paths.get(args[0]));

        SegmentInfos infos = new SegmentInfos();
        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            infos.add(getSegmentCommitInfo6(codec, directory, args[i]));
        }
        infos.commit(directory);
    }

    private static SegmentCommitInfo getSegmentCommitInfo(Codec codec, Directory directory, String segmentName) throws IOException {
        byte[] segmentID = new byte[StringHelper.ID_LENGTH];
        final String fileName = IndexFileNames.segmentFileName(segmentName, "", Lucene62SegmentInfoFormat.SI_EXTENSION);
        ChecksumIndexInput input = directory.openChecksumInput(fileName, IOContext.READ);
        DataInput in = new BufferedChecksumIndexInput(input);

        final int actualHeader = in.readInt();
        final String actualCodec = in.readString();
        final int actualVersion = in.readInt();
        in.readBytes(segmentID, 0, segmentID.length);

        SegmentInfo info = codec.segmentInfoFormat().read(directory, segmentName, segmentID, IOContext.READ);

        info.setCodec(codec);
        return new SegmentCommitInfo(info, 1, -1, -1, -1);
    }

    private static void help() {
        System.out.println("Not enough arguments");
        System.out.println("Usage: java -cp lucene-core-6.6.0.jar GenSegmentInfo <path to index> [segment1 [segment2 ...] ]");
    }
}
```

To get it work under Lucene410 library, following parts of the code must be adjusted as the library works differently:

- SimpleFSDirectory requires File instead of Path
- There is no checkIndexHeaderID function and segmentID is not needed
- SegmentInfo is available from codec.segmentInfoFormat().getSegmentInfoReader().read(directory, segmentName, IOContext.READ)

Answer (score 1):

For those using Lucene.NET, this is how to rebuild the segments file.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string dirPath = "path here";
    string filePrefix = "prefix here"; // ex: it's the _1 of _1.fdt, _1.fdx, etc.
    int numberOfFiles = 8;//this is how many files start with the given prefix

    SimpleFSDirectory directory = new SimpleFSDirectory(dirPath);
    SegmentInfos infos = new SegmentInfos();

    SegmentInfo si = new SegmentInfo(filePrefix, numberOfFiles, directory);
    infos.Add(si);
    infos.Commit(directory);
}
```